# parameter ‘my 2D-arr’ is initialized

Tags: c, arrays, cygwin, c99

Consider this code:

```
enum 
{
        ERR_START,
        ERR_CANNOTOPENFILE, 
        ERR_CANNOTCONNECT, 
        ERR_CANNOTCONNECTWITH,
        ERR_CANNOTGETHOSTNAME,
        ERR_CANNOTSEND,

};

char* ERR_MESSAGE[] =
{
    [ERR_START]                     = "Nothing",
    [ERR_CANNOTOPENFILE]            = "Cannot open '%s' filename.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTCONNECT]             = "Cannot connect.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTCONNECTWITH]         = "Cannot connect with '%s'.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTGETHOSTNAME]         = "Cannot get host name.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTSEND]                = "Cannot send.\n",

};
```

Given this erros:

```
error.h:27:1: error: parameter ‘ERR_MESSAGE’ is initialized
error.h:29:2: error: array index in non-array initializer
error.h:29:2: error: (near initialization for ‘ERR_MESSAGE’)
error.h:29:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
error.h:30:2: error: array index in non-array initializer
[....]
```

I'm compiling with `-std=c99`.

How to fix this?

Comment: What compiler, on what system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting this message because another syntax error in the file (or something included before it). I pasted the code into a standalone C file and got no compile errors with `gcc -std=c99 -c test.c` and my GCC version is **gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)**.

A likely error (maybe the only one) is if there's a function declaration that is missing a semicolon. With the code

```
enum 
{
        ERR_START,
        ERR_CANNOTOPENFILE, 
        ERR_CANNOTCONNECT, 
        ERR_CANNOTCONNECTWITH,
        ERR_CANNOTGETHOSTNAME,
        ERR_CANNOTSEND,

};

void foo()
char* ERR_MESSAGE[] =
{
    [ERR_START]                     = "Nothing",
    [ERR_CANNOTOPENFILE]            = "Cannot open '%s' filename.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTCONNECT]             = "Cannot connect.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTCONNECTWITH]         = "Cannot connect with '%s'.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTGETHOSTNAME]         = "Cannot get host name.\n",
    [ERR_CANNOTSEND]                = "Cannot send.\n",

};
```

I get the similar errors

```
est.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:13:1: error: parameter ‘ERR_MESSAGE’ is initialized
test.c:15:5: error: array index in non-array initializer
test.c:15:5: error: (near initialization for ‘ERR_MESSAGE’)
test.c:15:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:15:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘ERR_MESSAGE’) [enabled by default]
test.c:16:5: error: array index in non-array initializer
test.c:16:5: error: (near initialization for ‘ERR_MESSAGE’)
test.c:16:5: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]
test.c:16:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘ERR_MESSAGE’) [enabled by default]
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was saved my day. The error is exactly it. On my functionprototype.h header I forget put a `;` into function prototype; it's the reason that triggered something like 100 warings and erros.